# How to attach button to bottom in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to create screen like on the picture:

[image]

And I need to have that button at the bottom of the screen. However, the TextField can expand as user is typing, and at some point it can reach button at the bottom at which point button should move down...

[image]

I have no idea how to create this kind of layout... Like I need something like:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    Column(
        Text()
        TextField()
        Expanded()
        RaisedButton()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final appBar = AppBar(
    title: Text('Material App Bar'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  _buildBody(context) {
    final minHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: minHeight,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```